# Multi producer, multi consumer in Rabbit MQ with single queue

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, message-queue

I'm very new to RabbitMQ and I need to write a program that has Multi Producer and multi consumer with a single queue. Is this possible to do what I've shown in the image? I found lots of examples but they are all with single producer. Any producer send messages to any consumer.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, the answer is absolutely you can have many producers that publish to a single queue.  I would recommend that you create an exchange and have your producers send things into an exchange which then forwards to a queue.  In your simple diagram an exchange is not strictly necessary but it makes your solution more extensible in the future.

Comment: To be honest you do not need an exchange use this example https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-dotnet.html and add more producers sending to the same queue.  Queued items will be in the order that they are received and you will not be able to tell which queue sent it.  This is a work queue so each message is sent once to only one consumer not replicated.  If you need all consumers to see all messages then you need a different set up.

Comment: You are right we might need to expand the solution in future. @jhilden

Comment: @Diana, as a rule of thumb, I recommend that you always publish to an exchange vs publishing directly to a queue.  You'll find exchanges very useful in the future and it's better to have a consistent process.